# jQuery UI dialog - check if exists by instance method

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I'd like to use `instance` method for testing if jQuery UI Dialog widget has been initialized or not. Regarding to [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-instance), this is possible, but it doesn't work for me:

`Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'instance'`

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mDbV7/

**UPDATE:**

This was a mistake in the documentation, `instance` method will be available from version 1.11.0, see [this issue](https://github.com/jquery/api.jqueryui.com/issues/117).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The latest version of jQuery UI no longer allows you to call UI methods on items that are not initialized yet. I've just been wrapping them in an if statement, like:

```js
if ($("#divToBeDialoged").hasClass('ui-dialog-content')) {
    // do whatever
} else {
    // it is not initialized yet
}
```

Edit: changed class name, thanks @dmnc

Comment: so the API documentation is outdated?

Comment: @pavian, or the widget may be bugged.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#calling-an-invalid-method-now-throws-an-error

Comment: @jbabey, the [instance](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-instance) method is explicitly documented as being a special case.

Comment: The behavior was previously undefined and now throws exceptions, I believe it is working as intended, and the documentation for `instance` is outdated. Related defects: [8796](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8796), [6257](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6257). In any case, just use the if statement in my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've reported this as a [documentation issue](https://github.com/jquery/api.jqueryui.com/issues/117).

Comment: @jbabey, actually I found `ui-dialog-content` class with my "dialoged" div.

Comment: @pavian is correct, `#divToBeDialoged` gets the class `ui-dialog-content` not `ui-dialog`.

Answer (score 20):

It is also a good habit to empty and destroy dialogs once you're done using them.
I usually use this code in the close event of each dialog

```js
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    // other options
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).empty().dialog('destroy');
    }
}
```

That'd be my advice, rather than asking every time if a dialog exists in an instance make sure that each dialog cleans up after itself.

Comment: yeah, it saves from unpredicted bugs.

Comment: This is a very nice advice, specially if you are reusing  a dialog with different themes, thank you!

Comment: Note that all you need is `.dialog('destroy')` to be able to toggle the existence. `.empty()` will remove the content of the modal.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
if($('#id').is(':ui-dialog')) {
}
```

or

```js
    var obj = $('<div>test</div>').dialog();
    if (obj.is(':ui-dialog')) {
      alert('I\'m a dialog')
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So many solutions and no working example... [Here's a fiddle based on OP's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mDbV7/41/) showing it works in $v1.9.1.

Comment: that's true sorry, I add a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making that dialog from an existing id in your html code, like this example:

```js
$('#main').dialog({});
```

Notice that `dialog()` adds the class `ui-dialog` in a `<div>` parent element generated for it to work. At the `#main` element, the classes added by `dialog()` are: `ui-dialog-content` and `ui-widget-content` (in jquery-ui-1.9.2). So, in this case, following the example from @jbabey, you can check the existing dialog doing:

```js
if ($('#main').hasClass('ui-dialog-content')) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     if ($('#update').is(':data(dialog)')) 
     {
              //#update has dialog
     }
     else
     {
              //#update does't have dialog
     }
```

Comment: Nor me (jQ 1.9.1, ui 1.10.3)

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery UI - v1.10.3

```
if($( "#myDialog" ).is(':data(uiDialog)')){//is(':data(dialog)') does not work
    //Dialog exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is

```
$('.element').is(':data(dialog)');
```

Answer (score 0):

$("[aria-describedby="IDNAME"]").remove();  - if you want to remove same dialog, which makes as html code DATA

$("[aria-describedby="IDNAME"]") - element of Dialog with additional ID NAME. You can detect data by
($("[aria-describedby="IDNAME"]").lenght > 0)
or remove all dialog with this ID for prevent duplicate window.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).