# Disable/Enable draggable of jquery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, draggable

I made a draggable div in javascript. But while testing i realized that at certain points i had to disable the dragging feature, which was easy, until recently when i changed from 1.9.1 to 1.7.2 (For workrelated issues)

Now suddenly it doesn't work to enable/disable the dragging part.Any suggestions?

Comment: If you see any exceptions in the console saying "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on ____ prior to initialization; attempted to call method _____", you're probably having the same problem answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763909/jquery-ui-dialog-check-if-exists-by-instance-method/15763986#15763986).

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwser! But no, i get no such error. It accepts the call just fine. And as said, if i have 1.9.1 everything works, it just doesn't in 1.7.2 :/

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, i just realized it's because .animate() doesn't have the start: option in 1.7 -.- The disable part should work just fine.